# JMeter: auth2.0 Authentication Process (B2C Architecture)

Tags: authentication, jmeter, authorization, performance-testing, api-authorization

Steps:

1. Hitting the website- It is being redirected to an URL which contains parameters such as STATE, NONCE and CLIENT-REQUEST-ID which are dynamic.

So, in JMeter, I am unable to fetch those values as those are coming directly in a HTTP request.
Any Idea, how to fetch it?

2. While clicking on sign in with credentials, authentication process is happening which is generating a token id.
   Then in next request, redirects occur and same kind of URL is achieved (as in step1). Again same parameters are passed.
   And with this request, Access token is generated.

I am unable to fetch those parameter (nonce, state, client request id). Is there anything we can do?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adfsoal/5ba2fe65-14b6-4e80-92ee-55549ce74228), client-request-id is optional (so you can probably just leave it off) and if I read this right is generated by the client. So you may be able to just [generate a random GUID in JMeter](https://www.google.com/search?q=jmeter%20generate%20guid).

Answer (score 0):

If you're being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to an URL which contains the parameters you're looking for you should be able to capture them from the [sub-sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-)

[image]

using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)

[image]

Also some values like consumer key are static and never change and some values like [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) are random

If you don't need to load test the OAuth login challenge itself you can ask developers or administrators to provide you a permanent token which you can send in the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct but in my case I am not getting any sub-sampler(s).
That's where trouble lies!
Also, those parameters are coming from 3rd Party which is hosting the site(not in the hands of Devs)..
The whole process I am doing is for load testing.
So, any thing you wanna add for this?

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this ...?  i am running into the same issue.

Comment: @shahbaz Yes, I left those dynamically changing parameters empty. While sending the request, the parameters get updated on server level and thus access token is fetched. Though you won't see in the request section what those values are.